# How can I use CountdownTimer on a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, countdowntimer

I'm new to android studio and I'm trying to make a timer within a fragment. I want an app that starts a timer when I clicked a button.

this is my fragment code

```
public class tab3Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "tab3Fragment";

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer= new CounterClass(180000, 1000);
    private Button btn3;
    private TextView timer;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_fragment,container,false);
        timer= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timer);
btn3= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startBTN);

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        });
        return view;

    }

    public  class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer{
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis= millisUntilFinished;
            String hms= String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
            );
            timer.setText(hms);
        }
    }

}
```

i don't know if I'm right.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: what issue your facing now?

Comment: there are a lot of issues:

CounterClass() in CounterClass cannot be applied to (int, int)

and class 'CounterClass' must be either be declared abstract or implement abstract moethod 'onFinish()' in CountDownTimer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared your btn3 button. It's currently null.

You're supposed to implement the countdown timer like this

```
 CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new android.os.CountDownTimer(100,0){
             @Override
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                   long millis= millisUntilFinished;
            String hms= String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 

    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
                );
                timer.setText(hms);
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onFinish() {

                 }
             }
```

Comment: Override the method onFinish in your timer class

Comment: i'm sorry i dont know how to do that

never mind. its showing another error "there is no default constructor available in 'android.os.CountDownTimer'"

Comment: Wow it worked! thanks dude. I have one problem though the timer doesn't show 00:00:00 it stopped at 00:00:01.